# insertAdjacentElement and whitespace-only text node

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am using `insertAdjacentElement` method to add an element before another already existing one. While this works properly when I insert before a text element, when I insert an element before another element I get, in the middle, a whitespace-only text node (Firefox).

Any idea how can I prevent that node from being created? Or should I just try and delete it myself? :-/

```js
  let name = document.getElementById("foo");
  let mr = document.createElement("span");
  mr.textContent = "Mr";
  mr.setAttribute("class", "foo");
  name.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", mr);
```

```css
author { border: solid 1px #000000; }
span { border: solid 1px #ff0000; }
```

```html
<bibl id="foo">
  <author>John</author>
  <myTitle>Foo</myTitle>
  <page>bar</page>
</bibl>
```

Comment: Trying to reproduce with a JSFiddle. Will post as soon as it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty text node exists *in your code to begin with*, given the

```
<bibl id="foo">
  <author>John</author>
```

See the whitespace between the `>` of the `bibl` and the `<` of `author`.

Remove it and you won't see any space between the `Mr` and the author:

```js
let name = document.getElementById("foo");
  let mr = document.createElement("span");
  mr.textContent = "Mr";
  mr.setAttribute("class", "foo");
  name.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", mr);
```

```css
author { border: solid 1px #000000; }
span { border: solid 1px #ff0000; }
```

```html
<bibl id="foo"><author>John</author>
  <myTitle>Foo</myTitle>
  <page>bar</page>
</bibl>
```

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why that node wasn't shown before the JavaScript code run. Probably Firefox hiding hideous details :)